# Debian Jessie problems with dual monitors on laptop

Tags: debian, laptop, multi-monitor

I have recently installed Debian 8 (Jessie) on my laptop. 
I am using an external monitor as the primary display and the laptop monitor as a secondary display.

The laptop monitor shows text etc on startup and then goes blank when the login screen loads.

After logging in I can make the laptop monitor work by changing the resolution. After this the laptop monitor works until I log out again. 
It seems like it doesn't matter what resolution I change it to, just the act of changing the resolution makes it work.

I am using Gnome.

Can someone tell me how I can configure the system so that I do not have to do the aforementioned workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xrandr` to configure the screens directly after login by placing a script with the correct parameters into the autostart folder of your window manager or by putting the `xrandr` command directly into `~/.xsession`, e.g. (with LVDS and VGA being the names of your respective screens):

`xrandr --output LVDS --size 1024x768 --output VGA --size 1024x768 --right-of LVDS`

The `xrandr`-manpage shows some good examples of how to formulate a specific layout for one or two monitors.

You can use `xrandr --query` to list the current configuration of your screens and then use that output to set the attributes for your `xrandr` command.

If you put the `xrandr` command into `~/.xsession`, it should run in the background (just add `&` at the end of the line).